# 'Like Box' HTML - Spot the difference

Tags: facebook

Evening all,

I'm trying to embed 'Like Box' code on a new HTML-based website I am constructing on behalf of an amateur sports team.

The code provided by Facebook (see below) only works when logged into Facebook. When not logged in, it disappears from the website.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Abbots-Leigh-Cricket-Club/355894667759395" data-width="250" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

After realising this issue, I found a website displaying the plugin (code below) exactly how I wanted it to show on our website...

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcricinfo&amp;width=250&amp;height=248&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;border_color=0&amp;header=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:260px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#FFFFFF;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

...With that in mind, I adapted the code (see below) and expected it to work...

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FAbbots-Leigh-Cricket-Club%2F355894667759395&amp;width=250&amp;height=248&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;border_color=0&amp;header=false" " scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:260px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#FFFFFF;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

...But, the original issue still persists. Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Any help would be great as it's driving me up the wall!

Comment: When trying to access `https://www.facebook.com/pages/Abbots-Leigh-Cricket-Club/355894667759395`, Facebook just redirects me to the home page … are you sure that’s the _correct_ URL for the page …?

Comment: I believe so, CBroe, although I have the same issue. Could it be something to do with the settings of the Facebook page, perhaps?

Comment: Is it published yet (not only visible to admins)? Any restrictions on it (alcohol content, country, …)?

Comment: It is published, yes. I have put restrictions on it so that it's only visible to people viewing in the UK, Australia and South Africa. I will delete those now and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Well there you go – if you’re not logged in to Facebook, they can’t determine whether or not you are allowed to see that page … and therefor you are not offered the possibility to like it either.

Comment: @CBROE You cracked it! It was the country restrictions. It now works fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So, for Facebook pages with any kind of restrictions (alcohol related content, country, …):

If you’re not logged in to Facebook, they can’t determine whether or not you are allowed to see that page … and therefor you are not offered the possibility to like it either.